# Unexpected error when selecting current project's triggers in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script which runs every 10 minutes. I want to turn off / remove the trigger and when I select the 'Current project's triggers' option under the 'Resources' menu, I get 'An unexpected error has occurred'.

I have tried several times at different times with the same result. I have also tried selecting the 'All your triggers' option under the 'Resources' menu. I only have one trigger set up. I have been able to turn off / remove the trigger in the past.

I wonder whether it maybe because I may have selected the option when the script was about to run.

Any comments will be appreciated.

Michael

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you tried doing the same on a different browser? Also, report a bug if its specific to that browser.

Comment: Thank you. I was using Google Chrome Version 19.0.1084.52. Sorry I thought I was using a more recent version. Anyway I tried Firefox Version 18.0.2 (latest release) and I was able to remove my trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue. Turns out that I didn't have the most recent version of Chrome installed. Once I updated Chrome, the issue was resolved.